# Best way to make a wizard

Tags: macos, wizard

I need to make a wizard with multiple interactive pages  that gathers data from the user. Making so many pages is a tough work by making every single window.  Is there any simple class or command to manage it?

Comment: Tried `UINavigationController`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple approaches you could take to do this. First off you could use a `UINavigationController` which allows you to easily move between multiple view controllers. This is probably the best option if you are okay with using multiple view controllers.

To push to the next controller in a navigation stack you can use:

```
UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"someID"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

`UIScrollView` is also an option but would require careful manual memory management when items moved on and off screen, however this could be done all in one class.

```
[arrayOfViews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx,BOOL *stop) {
    UIView *subView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320 * idx, 0, 320, 480)];
    float randNum = arc4random() % 255;
    [subView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:randNum/255.0 green:randNum/255.0 blue:randNum/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
    [myScrollView addSubview:subView];
    [myScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320 * (idx + 1), 480)];
}];
```

Then your final and most flexible option would be to just make subviews of your main view and you could make your own custom animations for how every item moves around on screen.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
    [someSubview setTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5), CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-300, -300))];
}completion:^(BOOL done){
   //some completion items
}];
```

Comment: Thanks. But I meant coding for OSX. I think UINavigationController is only available for iOS. Am I right?

Comment: @user1642260 Sorry about that, but most of this should still be available in OS X, changing some UI's to NS's and fixing other problems accordingly.

Comment: how the heck is this the right answer? there's no NSNavigationController.

Comment: @ahmetalpbalkan I saw the notification for the first comment you left. A little rude, don't you think? And yeah, in retrospect, this does seem a little silly, but the question I answered was originally  tagged iOS, and I never claimed that NSNavigationController existed. I said that "most of this should still be available in OS X, changing some UI's to NS's and fixing other problems accordingly."

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on H2CO3's comment, you'll want to probably use a [UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), assuming the users are allowed to go backwards at will. Then, to go forwards, you'll just push a new UIViewController onto the stack.

Alternatively, you can check out storyboards, which let you define the whole thing, in a row, with transitions using IB. However, those end up being embedded in a UINavigationController anyway.